# What is the actual command that ^A | maps to in gnu screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

I have a version of gnu screen that allows vertical splitting with `^A |`.
I'm trying to pass a vertical split screen command to another window using `at`.

To do a horizontal split screen `at otherwindow split` works, but what command do I use for vertical split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is `split -v` which seems to be un(der)-documented.

Comment: Which version added that? Version 4.00.03 on Mac OS X Snow Leopard doesn't support that. It's certainly undocumented on the official GNU site.

Comment: @Doug: The only place I've seen it documented is in `^A:help` at the bottom left and in the ChangeLog. Apparently it was [added in version 4.1](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/ChangeLog).

Comment: Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06 on Mac OS 10.6.8 supports C-a |, but not 'split -v'